# Delete TokBox Archives

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTok [archiving](http://tokbox.com/opentok/docs/concepts/archiving.html) to record live video streams. Once I have recorded an archive, how do I delete it from the TokBox servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After recording an archive, you should get an archive id. Using this archive id, you can delete videos using [OpenTok rest api](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/), or calling a delete method using one of their [server side SDKs](https://github.com/opentok).

As for deleting all the videos, theres are no ways to retrieve all previously recorded videos, so you would have to be diligent about storing the archive ids.

Answer (score 0):

They provide a listArchives() API to list all the previously recorded archives. The list will have the id of the archive. Use the id in the deleteArchive(archiveId) API.

Comment: How does this answer OPs question?